# Inject record into DataList

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I would like suggestions on how to inject a record into my DataList to give an "All" option. Here is my code, data coming from the Northwind database.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        RepeatLayout="Flow" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
        onitemcommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemStyle CssClass="datalist" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#(((DataListItem)Container).ItemIndex+1).ToString() %>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnRegion" runat="server" 
          Text='<%# Eval("RegionDescription").ToString().Trim() %>'
        CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"RegionID")%>' />                    
    </ItemTemplate>       
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [RegionID], [RegionDescription] FROM [Region]" 
        ondatabinding="SqlDataSource1_Databinding" 
    onselected="SqlDataSource1_Selected">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am using the Link button in the Datalist to filter the territories and display them in a GridView.
**What I would like to do is at some in the databinding process, add an Item in the DataList that will act as the ALL option**, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbtn;

    foreach (DataListItem dli in DataList1.Items)
    {
        lbtn = (LinkButton)dli.FindControl("lbtnRegion");
        if (lbtn != null)
            lbtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
    string command = e.CommandName;
    lbtn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbtnRegion");
    if (lbtn != null)
        lbtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen;

    DataView dv = GetData(ref command); // Pass the RegionId
    gvTerritory.DataSource = dv;
    gvTerritory.DataBind();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to UNION ALL a 'All' value to the query fetching the list of drop down items.

```
SELECT 'All', 'All Regions' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT [RegionID], [RegionDescription] FROM [Region]
```

But if you have a lot of lists (or dropdowns) like this, it is better practice to create a custom control that injects an 'All' record for you.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with the following SQL:

```
SELECT '-1' AS 'RegionID', 'All Regions' AS 'RegionDescription' 
UNION ALL SELECT [RegionID], [RegionDescription] FROM [Region]
```

Answer (score 0):

Used this on a drop down, may work the same on a datalist

```
  Protected Sub ddlDataSources_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlDataSources.DataBound
    ddlDataSources.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("All Data Sources", 0))
  End Sub
```